# Issue with cordova camera plugin on Kitkat OS

Tags: javascript, java, android, cordova

I am using cordova camera plugin to take picture and later upload it to the server.I have been using lollipop OS in my phone and it works pretty well in my phone.However when I test the app on my friend's phone which is running on Kitkat operating system, an error message is thrown.The screenshot for the same is given below.

[image]

The file URI for the given image is something like
'file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.app.name/cache/filename.jpg'.My JavaScript code is given below

```
 //function that gets called when clicking capture photo button
                function capturePhoto() {
                navigator.camera.getPicture(onCapturePhoto, onFail, {
                quality: 50,
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
                });



 function onCapturePhoto(fileURI) {

                var win = function (r) {
                clearCache();
                retries = 0;
                BootstrapDialog.alert('Done uploading image!');
                var img = JSON.parse(r.response);
                $("#clientid_issue_id").val(img.id.$id);
                construct_img_thumbnail_view(img);
                $("#go_to_issue_report_btn").prop('disabled', false);
                }

                var fail = function (error) {
                if (retries == 0) {
                retries++
                setTimeout(function () {
                onCapturePhoto(fileURI)
                }, 5000)
                } else {
                retries = 0;
                clearCache();
                BootstrapDialog.alert('Ups. Something wrong happens!' + JSON.stringify(error));
                $("#go_to_issue_report_btn").prop('disabled', false);
                }
                }

                var options = new FileUploadOptions();
                options.fileKey = "file";
                options.fileName = fileURI.substr(fileURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
                var params = new Object();
                params.client_device_id = device.uuid;
                params.client_issue_id = $("#clientid_issue_id").val();
                if (params.client_issue_id.trim() === "")
                {
                params.client_issue_id = 0;
                }
                options.params = params; // if we need to send parameters to the server request
                var ft = new FileTransfer();
                $("#go_to_issue_report_btn").prop('disabled', true);
                ft.upload(fileURI, encodeURI(SERVER_PATH + "/services/uploadimage"), win, fail, options);
                }
```

The version of cordova I am using is 5.1.1.The AndroidManifest.xml file is given below.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="com.example.hello" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"/>
</manifest>
```

Here is my config.xml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.example.hello" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <name>HelloWorld</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <feature name="Whitelist">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.whitelist.WhitelistPlugin" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Camera">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Device">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.device.Device" />
    </feature>
    <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Internal" />
    <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
    <feature name="File">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="FileTransfer">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.filetransfer.FileTransfer" />
    </feature>
</widget>
```

It would be very helpful if someone could tell me the solution.

Comment: Seems that your server is blocking your request

Comment: @lifeisfoo The same app works fine on my phone which is running on lollipop and the image gets uploaded on server so I think it may not be the issue with the server.Screenshot is from phone which works on Kitkat OS.

Comment: The image file is found at 'Android/data/com.app.name/cache/filename.jpg' in both the phones but only the phone working on lollipop OS actually uploads the image to server.

Comment: Have you debugged the request on the server?

Comment: can u share the php server side code which manages the upload

Comment: @lifeisfoo you are right ,the value of SERVER_PATH variable is read from a text file stored in the phone and when I alert encodeURI(SERVER_PATH + "/services/uploadimage"), I do not get the proper server path.This is why it is showing 403 error.I corrected it and now everything is working fine.

Comment: Please answer yourself using all the information I provided you and accept the answer, so other people could resolve similar problems. If my suggestions/comments were useful for you, vote them.

Comment: @lifeisfoo Yes I have done that.Thanks for the help friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found out the issue.The value of SERVER_PATH variable is read from an external text file **read.txt** stored on the device.So in my friends mobile,the read.txt is edited with an App called Kingsoft office.The path is given like '**http://192.168....../e-gov/web/services/uploadimage**' which is the correct server path and saved.The application starts and works fine reading the value from the file.But in the code section for taking picture and upload, I used like  'ft.upload(fileURI, **encodeURI(SERVER_PATH + "/services/uploadimage")**, win, fail, options);'. I used **alert(encodeURI(SERVER_PATH + "/services/uploadimage"))** to check whether the server path is right.Surprizingly the value alerted was '**http://192.168..../e-gov/web%0D%0A/services/uploadimage**' which was not the actual server address.So I send the read.txt file from my phone to friends mobile and tested the app again.Now even if I do use **encodeURI** I get the correct server address.Hope this might be useful to some other people who may ran into same sort of situation.